# UNITY, SHADER Fog of War shader causing unity crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

Yesterday I had implemented Fog of war for my RTS game. All was working fine last night before I went to bed, I checked it scene by scene and ran through loads of tests to make sure it was working and all was good.

But today, when I try and run the game, it loads the main menu, but when it tries to load the first level, unity crashes and doesn't give me a reason.

I tried going through code and game objects until I found that if I removed the custom shader attached to the terrain I was using to create fog over the map, it would stop crashing unity and continue running the game, however I reattached it and it ran fine again with the fog of war working again, but as soon as i closed unity and opened it again, the same problem occurred with crashing loading the first level.

I am unsure if it is the shader or the code for it thats causing the problem.
I have little experience with shaders but if anyone can have a look at the code for it and tell me if anything looks wrong with it I would be very greatful.

```
    Shader "Fog Of War/Terrain" {
    Properties {
        _FOWTex ("Detail", 2D) = "gray" {}

        // Splat Map Control Texture
        [HideInInspector] _Control ("Control (RGBA)", 2D) = "red" {}
        [HideInInspector] _Splat3 ("Layer 3 (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _Splat2 ("Layer 2 (B)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _Splat1 ("Layer 1 (G)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _Splat0 ("Layer 0 (R)", 2D) = "white" {}

        // used in fallback on old cards & base map
        // [HideInInspector] _MainTex ("BaseMap (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        // [HideInInspector] _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" 
                "SplatCount" = "4"
            }
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert nolightmap

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_FOWTex;
            float2 uv_Control : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv_Splat0 : TEXCOORD1;
            float2 uv_Splat1 : TEXCOORD2;
            float2 uv_Splat2 : TEXCOORD3;
            float2 uv_Splat3 : TEXCOORD4;
        };

        sampler2D _Control, _FOWTex;
        sampler2D _Splat0,_Splat1,_Splat2,_Splat3;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 splat_control = tex2D (_Control, IN.uv_Control);
            fixed3 col;
            col  = splat_control.r * tex2D (_Splat0, IN.uv_Splat0).rgb;
            col += splat_control.g * tex2D (_Splat1, IN.uv_Splat1).rgb;
            col += splat_control.b * tex2D (_Splat2, IN.uv_Splat2).rgb;
            col += splat_control.a * tex2D (_Splat3, IN.uv_Splat3).rgb;
            o.Albedo = col;
            fixed3 c = tex2D (_FOWTex, IN.uv_FOWTex).aaa;
            c = 1-c;
            o.Albedo *= c;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack off
}
```

Comment: If it's causing unity to crash then maybe you would be better off creating a ticket at their issue tracker site and giving them your crash log as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that a shader is causing the application to crash. If there is an issue with a shader, then Unity will fail to compile the shader and anything which used it will be rendered solid bright pink.

I don't see anything terribly wrong in the shader, however this line:

```
float2 uv_FOWTex;
```

in your input struct I think is probably unnecessary.

To debug it, you could strip down your Fog of War shader to as basic and simple as you can get it. Then see if it keeps crashing. It it doesn't, then gradually add back in pieces of the shader until it does.

But when it comes to crashes usually it's from you doing something bad with calls to unmanaged code.